# PDFTextStripper not support for multiple language in same PDF

Tags: java

I'am trying to Extract multi language PDF file(Arabic and English) by using PDFTextStripper it's Extract English words as reverse order

```
PDDocument pddDocument = PDDocument.load(new File("C://Users/Lap361/Desktop/DEMO/4530300163-TL.pdf"));
PDFTextStripper textStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
String Text = textStripper.getText(pddDocument);
System.out.println("Text--"+Text1);
```

OutPut is:
 esneciL laicremmoC رقم الرخصة  تفاصيل الرخصة  /  sliateD esneciL
 065755  .oN esneciL اليقاع التقليدي  للزياء (شركة ذات مسؤولية محدودة
 )اسم الشركة emaN ynapmoC(C.L.L) NOIHSAF MHTYHR CISSALC )C.L.L( NOIHSAF
 MHTYHR CISSALC اليقاع التقليدي للزياء )ش.ذ.م.م( emaN edarT السم
 التجارى etaD yripxEتاريخ النتهاءتاريخ الصدار etaD eussI .oN ® S-N-U-D
 B&D رقم الرخصة الم ذات مسئولية محدودة 4002/50/62 9102/50/52 065755
 epyT lageLالشكل القانونى  esneciL niaM .oN 373455435 الرقم العالمي
 03976 92778 رقم السجل التجارى.oN ICCDعضوية الغرفة .oN retsigeR

Comment: this documentation will help you to export PDF files. https://itnext.io/javascript-convert-html-css-to-pdf-print-supported-very-sharp-and-not-blurry-c5ffe441eb5e

Comment: Thanks Aras..But above problem has been solved when i migrate BDFbox version 1.8 to 2.0...thanks